# how to dump user-space stack in kernel space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I already used dump_stack() function. but this function is not what I want.

I want to know how to dump user-space stack in kernel space.

Also, dump result must be output in kernel log.

Thanks.

p.s. Thank you for your understanding about my question because I don't know English grammar well.

Comment: You want to know what's running on each cpu core and if it is user space then dump it to dmesg ?

Comment: if short - there is no tool that can solve this task. But if you will give more background, maybe I could help you. I mean describe what are conditions, when you want to dump user space stack

Comment: Why would you want to dump a user space stack in kernel space? However, you can enable a config symbol assuming it's not enabled called CONFIG_DEBUG_USER and pass the kernel argument user_debug=31, which 
enables various messages in case a user space application crashes.

Comment: @Sanchayan sometimes it is useful to know, how you reach the point in kernel code from user space. Imagine you tracking memory allocations

Comment: @AlexHoppus I want to dump some system call that is invoked.

The dumped result means the stack frame and not the memory data.

Comment: @JGosu why you can't just place a breakpoint at gdb? What is the need of doing this from kernel. I just want to be confident that you problem couldn't be resolved from userspace.

Comment: @AlexHoppus Now I have been studying the anti-analysis technique and anti-analysis evasion technique. I can not use the GDB that use the ptrace because Debugger-blocker technique. So I will solve this problem in kernel space.

Comment: @JGosu i wanted to propose some mix with gdb & kernel code, but if you can't use gdb this is not for you. The kernel solution will be too complex in terms of code and time.